# Convert function template into templated functor

Tags: c++, c++11, functor

I'm wondering whether it might be possible to create function objects from function templates. The following `Functor` struct creates a function object from a function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, F* f>
struct Functor {
  template <typename... Ar>
  auto operator()(Ar&&... rg) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...)) {
    return f(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...);
  }
};

int plus_one(int a) {
  return a + 1;
}

int main () {

  std::cout << Functor<decltype(plus_one), &plus_one>()(1) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This creates a structure like

```cpp
struct PlusOne {
  int operator()(int a) {
    return a + 1;
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to work with a function template instead of a function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T plus_one(T a) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

which I'm hoping to turn into something like

```cpp
struct PlusOne {
  template <class T>
  T operator()(T a) {
    return a + 1;
  }
};
```

Is this possible? One of the reasons I'm asking this is that I [read](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3559.pdf)  generic lambda expressions in C++14 are being turned into functors similar to what I'm after:

> For example, this generic lambda-expression containing statement:
>
> ```
>  auto L = [](const auto& x, auto& y){ return x + y; };
> ```
>
> might result in the creation of a closure type, and object that behaves similar to the struct below:
>
> ```
> struct {
>   template <typename T, typename U>
>   auto operator()(const T& x, U& y) const { return x + y; }
> } L;
> ```

So I was naively hoping some facilities for making possible what I'm after, might exist. I'm restricted to C++11 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  A template name by itself can be used in very limited ways.  You have to wrap it in a class before passing it around.  In C++14, using a lambda to wrap the call to the function seems to be the simplest possible way.  Then you can use it in many ways:

```
auto wrapper = [](const auto& x){ return plus_one(x); }

std::cout << wrapper(42) << "\n";
std::cout << std::invoke(wrapper, 42) << "\n";
std::cout << std::bind(wrapper, 42)() << "\n";
// etc.
```

In C++11, we are kinda screwed up.  We have to write the wrapper by ourselves:

```
struct Wrapper {
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& x) const
    {
        return plus_one(x);
    }
};
```

then

```
Wrapper wrapper;
// same usage
```